# C#Webclient downloadfileasync not working

Tags: c#

```
   /// <summary>  
    /// 下载更新  
    /// </summary>  
    public string Update()
    {
        string result = "";
        try
        {
            if (!isUpdate)
                return result;
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string filename = "Update_NewVersion.zip";
            filename = Path.GetDirectoryName(loadFile) + "\\" + filename;

            FinalZipName = filename;
            //wc.DownloadFile(download, filename);//能下载成功

            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(download), filename);//使用DownloadFileAsync下载不成功，能正常运行代码，但是执行后没有下载到zip文件，
            //wc.Dispose();
            return result = "download：" + download + ",filename:" + filename;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("更新出现错误，网络连接失败！" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
  void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as WebClient).Dispose();
        if (e.Error != null)
            throw e.Error;
        else
            isFinish();
    }

    void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CommonMethod.autostep = e.ProgressPercentage;
        //Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

The download file code using downloadfileasync works normally, but it is not downloaded to the file after execution. It has been tested that downloadfile can be downloaded to the file normally。

Comment: You shouldn't be using `WebClient` anymore - is there a reason you're not using `HttpClient` instead?

Comment: So, what do you know about methods that end with the word Async?

Comment: @CaiusJard `WebClient` is an exception to the "`Async`-suffix means TPL" rule: its _full_ of Async-suffixed methods that return `void`, instead it uses `EventHandler` events to return asynchronously. Yes, it's horrible.

Comment: Yes; I'm keen to see if the OP understands asynchrony at all; e.g. are they hoping their download will be fire and forget and they consciously used this construct for a particular reason, rather than ..Async being about TAP/TaskAsync specifically (in WC case) - ends up, methods named ..Async "behave in an asynchronous way" regardless the underlying mechanism, but they're often misunderstood because people are so used to programming synchronously

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the program completed the running before the download finished? It is a possible reason if your app is a console application.

Following comes from mdsn:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=net-5.0

This method does not block the calling thread while the resource is being downloaded. To block while waiting for the download to complete, use one of the DownloadFile methods.